# StringBuilder vs concatenating strings and int(or any other number)

Tags: java

What is better

```
int i = 45;
String str = "dsfgdsgf"+i;
```

or

```
int i = 45;
String str = new StringBuilder().append("dsfgdsgf").append(i).toString();
```

I have read somewhere that StringBuilder is always better than concatenating strings

Comment: but less readable for simple cases

Comment: When just concatenating two strings, the overhead of creating the `StringBuilder` instance will probably outweigh the benefits. Use it when building up a String from multiple parts (multiple >> 2).

Comment: in your example with concatenating constants it's an overkill, as compiler will optimize this. But in general when working with dynamic data it's more beneficial to use StringBuilder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference in performance, as the compiler will internally convert the first version to the second one.

Since the first version is more readable you should use it when you concatenate a fixed number of items into a string.

Use `StringBuilder` when you append to a string many times, for example in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't performance difference in both cases: [prooflink](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.2). Compiler use StringBuilder implicitly to concatenate String.

Of course **1** case is much more readable than **2** in most cases.

Also no big differences in explicit casting of Integer values:

StringBuilder casting use [AbstractStringBuilder#append(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.append%28int%29) and explicit casting using [String#valueOf(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) call [Integer#toString(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28int%29) internaly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just concatenating values in a known format, consider:

```
int i = 45;
String str = String.format("%s%d", "dsfgdsgf", i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Java are immutable objects. This means by writing `String str = "dsfgdsgf"+i;` you are actually creating a new String object and leave the old object for the Garbage Collector.

`StringBuilder` on the other hand is a mutable object so that the object is modified. Preferably you should use `StringBuilder.append()` or `StringBuffer.append()` whenever possible.

Note that `StringBuilder` is not `synchronized`, while `StringBuffer` is.

Comment: If you are using BiasLocking, the shouldn't difference: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/6-performance-137236.html#2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

We should be using StringBuilder, if you are modifying a string many times by appending, removing etc.In you case, you are using StringBuilder and again converting it to String.I dont think you are saving much with the second approach,since you are creating a new StringBuilder object and appending and again converting it to String

Answer (score 1):

Yes, StringBuilder is better than concatenating string. When you use following line of code `String str = "dsfgdsgf"+i;`

it uses StringBuilder internally. So you are just avoiding extra step by using StringBuilder directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option is better because it's impossible to concatenate with a String; therefore the String must be converted first to a StringBuilder before doing the concatenation and then have the result converted back to a String.